# Drawing servers Rack using html/css or any python library

Tags: python, html, css, rack, rackspace

is there any library or template that can help me draw servers rack , based on the server's position in this rack?

example :

- server_name -  start U -  End U
- servers1  -  15  -  17
- server2  -   20  -  25
- firewall -  2  -  4
- NAS    -  10  -  15

thank you for your help

Comment: what result do you expect? You can use `Pillow` to draw image `PNG`, `JPG`, or some module to generate `SVG` image. OR maybe you should simply create list and generate table using normal text. But first you have to read your data and parse it to create list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you need - image PNG/JPG, image SVG, text table, HTML table.

But first it would need to read data and convert to list like this

```
rows = [
   [1, 'empty']
   [2, 'firewall']
   [3, 'firewall']
   [4, 'firewall']
   [5, 'empty']

   # ... etc... 
]
```

With this list it could be simpler to calculate positions for text on image, or generate text table, or generate HTML.

You could use it with `tabulate` to generate text table
which you can display in HTML in `<pre></pre>` or `<code></code>`

```
+------+----------+
|   Nr | Device   |
+======+==========+
|    1 | ?        |
+------+----------+
|    2 | firewall |
+------+----------+
|    3 | firewall |
+------+----------+
|    4 | firewall |
+------+----------+
|    5 | ?        |
+------+----------+
|    6 | ?        |
+------+----------+
|    7 | ?        |
+------+----------+
|    8 | ?        |
+------+----------+
|    9 | ?        |
+------+----------+
|   10 | NAS      |
+------+----------+
|   11 | NAS      |
+------+----------+
|   12 | NAS      |
+------+----------+
|   13 | NAS      |
+------+----------+
|   14 | NAS      |
+------+----------+
|   15 | NAS      |
+------+----------+
|   16 | servers1 |
+------+----------+
|   17 | servers1 |
+------+----------+
|   18 | ?        |
+------+----------+
|   19 | ?        |
+------+----------+
|   20 | server2  |
+------+----------+
|   21 | server2  |
+------+----------+
|   22 | server2  |
+------+----------+
|   23 | server2  |
+------+----------+
|   24 | server2  |
+------+----------+
|   25 | server2  |
+------+----------+
```

---

Minimal working code for text table

```
text = '''servers1 - 15 - 17
server2 - 20 - 25
firewall - 2 - 4
NAS - 10 - 15'''

import io

# --- read to dictionary ---

data = {}
counter = {}

with io.StringIO(text) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        name, start, end = line.split(' - ')
        start = int(start)
        end = int(end)

        # - count -
        counter[name] = end-start+1
        
        for x in range(start, end+1):
            data[x] = name

# - display counter -
#print(counter)
for name, number in counter.items():
    print(f'{name:10}: {number}')
            
# --- convert to list ---

rows = []
last = max(data.keys())

for x in range(1, last+1):
    if x in data:
        name = data[x]
    else:
        name = '?'
    rows.append([x, name])
    
#print(rows)

# --- display table ---

import tabulate

print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, headers=['Nr', 'Device'], tablefmt='grid'))

# - count -
import collections
counter = collections.Counter(data.values())

# - display counter -
#print(counter)
for name, number in counter.items():
    print(f'{name:10}: {number}')
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you put `rows` in `pandas.DataFrame` then you can use `.to_html()` to generate it as `<table></table>`

But you can use `rows` also to generate `<table>` manually

```
table = "<table>\n"

table += "  <tr>\n    <th>Nr</th>\n    <th>Device</th>\n  </tr>\n"

for number, device in rows:
    table += f"  <tr>\n    <td>{number}</td>\n    <td>{device}</td>\n  </th>\n"

table += "</table>\n"

print(table)
```

Result:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nr</th>
    <th>Device</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>firewall</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>firewall</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>firewall</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>NAS</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>NAS</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>NAS</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>NAS</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>NAS</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>NAS</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>servers1</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>servers1</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>server2</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>server2</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>server2</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>server2</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>server2</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>server2</td>
  </th>
</table>
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you use `flask` then you can send `rows` to template

```
return render_template('template.html', rows=rows)
```

and run loop directly in template

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>Nr</th>
     <th>Device</th>
  </tr>

{% for number, device in rows %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{ number }}</td>
     <td>{{ device }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}  

</table>
```

Comment: thank you furas, what I need, is just an HTML presentation of my server rack with the name of each server and its position in the rack, I'm using python flask and my data is stored in MySQL. your response is very helpful I'll test it and get back to you asap.

Comment: if you use `flask` then you could do it directly inside template in `flask` - send `rows` to template and use `{% for loop %}`

Comment: I added example with `flask`

Comment: thank you very much... it works, do you have any idea how Merge cells in tabulate or HTML table.

Comment: in HTML you can use `colspan=number_of_columns` or `rowspan=number_of_rows` in `<td>`

Comment: how can i extract the number_of_rows of each device from this list with [number ; device]... thank you.

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to get this from original data - `server2 - 20 - 25` - `25-20+1 = 6`. But this can't count empty elements. For data `[number ; device]` it would need to run loop and use some counter - ie. dictionary and use `data[device] += 1` or use class `collections.Counter()`

Comment: I added both methods in answer in minimal working code. Look for `# - count -`. First method counts when I read `server2 - 20 - 25`, and second method counts at the end.

Comment: how can i combine these two lists, the rows, and counter, can we add empty rows to the counter dictionary... thank you

Comment: in first code I have loop `for x in range(1, last+1):` which draws `?` in empty places - but you could use it to detect empty places. To combine rows and counter you could use only first `for`-loop with some modification - there is `counter[name] = end-start+1` but you can use `counter[(start, end)] = (name, end-start+1)` or list with item `[start, end, name, end-start+1]` and when you sort it then you get devices with correct order and you have all information to draw all rows for this device. But all this is new problem and you should rather ask new question on new page.